# How can I calculate the tension at an angle in string at here by considering the vertical component of tension?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces

[image]

The answer said if vertical component of the tension was considered, it will be 775N. Without considering it, i got 1154N.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\text{N2L}:\qquad\sum \vec F=\frac{\mathrm d\vec p}{\mathrm dt}=m\vec a=\vec 0\\
\nwarrow+\text{ve}:\qquad T\sin20^\circ+N-mg\cos35^\circ=0\\
\nearrow+\text{ve}:\qquad T\cos20^\circ-\mu_kN-mg\sin35^\circ=0\\
N=mg\cos35^\circ-T\sin20^\circ\\
T\cos20^\circ-\mu_kmg\cos35^\circ+\mu_kT\sin20^\circ=mg\sin35^\circ
$$
I get 934N rather than 775N, and these equations agree with your 1154N if we neglect that component.